# Creating a Python Distribution: Trouble inlcluding HTML & JS etc files

Tags: python, django, sdist

I'm using the following script to create a python distribution, a theme/templates set for Pinax.  The files are mostly HTML & JS, with the Python files there more for configuration purposes:

```
import os
import sys
from fnmatch import fnmatchcase
from distutils.util import convert_path
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

VERSION = __import__('pinax-designer-theme').__version__

def read(*path):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *path)).read()

# Provided as an attribute, so you can append to these instead
# of replicating them:
standard_exclude = ('*.py', '*.pyc', '*~', '.*', '*.bak')
standard_exclude_directories = ('.*', 'CVS', '_darcs', './build',
                                './dist', 'EGG-INFO', '*.egg-info')

# Copied from paste/util/finddata.py
def find_package_data(where='.', package='', exclude=standard_exclude,
        exclude_directories=standard_exclude_directories,
        only_in_packages=False, show_ignored=False):
    """
    Return a dictionary suitable for use in ``package_data``
    in a distutils ``setup.py`` file.

    The dictionary looks like::

        {'package': [files]}

    Where ``files`` is a list of all the files in that package that
    don't match anything in ``exclude``.

    If ``only_in_packages`` is true, then top-level directories that
    are not packages won't be included (but directories under packages
    will).

    Directories matching any pattern in ``exclude_directories`` will
    be ignored; by default directories with leading ``.``, ``CVS``,
    and ``_darcs`` will be ignored.

    If ``show_ignored`` is true, then all the files that aren't
    included in package data are shown on stderr (for debugging
    purposes).

    Note patterns use wildcards, or can be exact paths (including
    leading ``./``), and all searching is case-insensitive.
    """

    out = {}
    stack = [(convert_path(where), '', package, only_in_packages)]
    while stack:
        where, prefix, package, only_in_packages = stack.pop(0)
        for name in os.listdir(where):
            fn = os.path.join(where, name)
            if os.path.isdir(fn):
                bad_name = False
                for pattern in exclude_directories:
                    if (fnmatchcase(name, pattern)
                        or fn.lower() == pattern.lower()):
                        bad_name = True
                        if show_ignored:
                            print >> sys.stderr, (
                                "Directory %s ignored by pattern %s"
                                % (fn, pattern))
                        break
                if bad_name:
                    continue
                if (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(fn, '__init__.py'))
                    and not prefix):
                    if not package:
                        new_package = name
                    else:
                        new_package = package + '.' + name
                    stack.append((fn, '', new_package, False))
                else:
                    stack.append((fn, prefix + name + '/', package, only_in_packages))
            elif package or not only_in_packages:
                # is a file
                bad_name = False
                for pattern in exclude:
                    if (fnmatchcase(name, pattern)
                        or fn.lower() == pattern.lower()):
                        bad_name = True
                        if show_ignored:
                            print >> sys.stderr, (
                                "File %s ignored by pattern %s"
                                % (fn, pattern))
                        break
                if bad_name:
                    continue
                out.setdefault(package, []).append(prefix+name)
    return out

excluded_directories = standard_exclude_directories + ('./requirements', './scripts')
package_data = find_package_data(exclude_directories=excluded_directories)

setup(
    name='pinax-designer-theme',
    version=VERSION,
    description='Pinax Designer Theme is a designer framework of django HTML(5) templates and Less.js CSS files, including a CSS grid, for Pinax.',
    long_description=read('docs', 'index.rst'),
    author='Daryl Antony',
    author_email='daryl@commoncreative.com.au',
    maintainer='Daryl Antony',
    maintainer_email='daryl@commoncreative.com.au',
    url='http://commoncreative.com.au/',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data=package_data,
    zip_safe=False,
    # entry_points={
    #         # 'console_scripts': [
    #         #             'pinax-admin = pinax.core.management:execute_from_command_line',
    #         #         ],
    #     },
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Environment :: Web Environment',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Framework :: Django',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.4',
        'Programming Language :: JavaScript',
    ],
)
```

This has been copied and modified from the actual Pinax `setup.py`.

Now, whilst the `package_data` variable seems to contain all of the necessary files, i.e. after doing:

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

and finding that the contents of package_data is:

http://dpaste.org/ojM0/

None of these files, except for the directories and *.py files seem to be actually included in the package.

So the question is, what can I do to change this?  And why is the contents of the `package_data` variable being ignored?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to specify those files in MANIFEST.in.

Comment: Hmmm, manually, or is there someway to do this automatically?

Comment: Oh I see `recursive-include` ?

Comment: I had the same problem, and I included the files manually in MANIFEST, then it works ... However that can't be the only solution !!! Otherwise why would there be a parameter `package_data` ?!?